# Algorithm for merge join with inequality condition

Tags: database, algorithm, oracle

I read that Oracle supports merge join with inequality join predicates.
Is there online reference to algorithm used in implementation of such join ?
If anyone knows how to do that, Can you put it in answer?

Comment: is this that different from equality join ?

Comment: @Prafulla: if your question has not been answered, you should consider flagging it for migration to (the sister site): dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_join.htm#TGSQL94691) is what you're looking for.

> 7.4 Sort Merge Joins
>
> Sort merge joins can join rows from two independent sources. In
>   general, hash joins perform better than sort merge joins. However,
>   sort merge joins can perform better than hash joins if both of the
>   following conditions exist:
>
> The row sources are sorted. A sort operation is not required. However,
>   if a sort merge join involves choosing a slower access method (an
>   index scan as opposed to a full table scan), then the benefit of using
>   a sort merge might be lost.
>
> Sort merge joins are useful when the join condition between two tables
>   is an inequality condition such as <, <=, >, or >=. Sort merge joins
>   perform better than nested loops joins for large data sets. Hash joins
>   require an equality condition.
>
> In a merge join, there is no concept of a driving table. The join
>   consists of two steps:
>
> Sort join operation
>
> Both the inputs are sorted on the join key.
>
> Merge join operation
>
> The sorted lists are merged.
>
> If the input is sorted by the join column, then a sort join operation
>   is not performed for that row source. However, a sort merge join
>   always creates a positionable sort buffer for the right side of the
>   join so that it can seek back to the last match in the case where
>   duplicate join key values come out of the left side of the join.

Answer (score -1):

There's an example here: http://www.serkey.com/oracle-skyline-query-challenge-bdh859.html

Is this what you're looking to do? (key word is "soft-merge")

Comment: It was posted nearly two years ago - look in the wayback machine

Comment: "The machine that serves this file is down. We're working on it."  This is why most link-only answers get deleted these days.

Comment: Yeah, but he did ask for an "online reference to algorithm"