# how sql engine handle join query with non-equal?

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

sql engine would use HashJoin if a query like this:

> select * from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;

that's fine. but if the query is like this:

> select * from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id > t2.id;

how to handle this?

the nestedloop join would work, but is there any better way?

Comment: MySQL does not even support hash indices, if I remember correctly.  But, which database are you actually using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh, i am study prestodb. the question just come to me suddenly today. so how sql engine handle this condition?

Comment: It depends on the query, data, indices, etc.  A B-tree index should still be usable with an inequality.

Comment: You might be interested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21128826).  Wikipedia has an entry on the cited [sort-merge-join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

For distributed SQL, a straight up non-qual join (`t1.id > t2.id`) is pretty expensive to execute.  If one side is small you do a broadcast, and then use a sorted index on every node.  If both sides are large, you can to range partition one and build a sorted index, and then replicate the other rows to any range that might match.

Normally, you have a combination equality and non-equal join like `t1.id = t2.id and t1.cost < t2.cost`.  In that case, case you can do a normal distributed hash join, and then keep a sorted list of the secondary items to perform the non-equal part.  This is what Presto does.